# Close all divs with same class at once when one ot them is ckicked (except the one we click on)

Tags: javascript, toggle

Project: Close all other divs with same class at once when we click on one, except of course the one we click on.

I found here 2 parts of code that I think could do it, but I do not know how to put it together.

To get my elements with same class (MaxPackage) - I am aware not all browser handle the getElement...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("MaxPackage");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
// elements[i].style ...               <-- I do not know what this means 
}
```

And the part I found (as is) that could do the toggle part I think:

```
var prevId;
function toggle_visibility(id) {
if(prevId && id !== prevId){
  $("#"+prevId).slideToggle("slow");
}
var e = document.getElementById(id);
  $(e).slideToggle("slow");
prevId = id;
}
```

Thank you for your help, I am not a programmer, so please do not be afraid to explain :) Then I will need to know how to trigger it (onload or add function in element)?

Edited: I got a very simple solution:

```
 $('div.MaxPackage').click(function(){
 $('div.MaxPackage').hide();
 $(this).show();
 });
```

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for this problem?

Comment: I got a simple solution, thanks for your help! Here is the jsfidle:   $('div.MaxPackage').click(function(){
   $('div.MaxPackage').hide();
   $(this).show();
});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergelie/ja8aS/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is a very simple vanilla javascript way to get what you want

```
<div class="MaxPackage" onclick="closeThem(event)">one</div>
<div class="MaxPackage" onclick="closeThem(event)">two</div>
<div class="MaxPackage" onclick="closeThem(event)">three</div>
<div class="MaxPackage" onclick="closeThem(event)">four</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function closeThem(e) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('MaxPackage');
    for (var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (e.target !== divs[i]) {
            divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It only works with one hard coded class, not the class of the div that was clicked on

Comment: that's easy enough to implement but the questioner stated he was not a programmer so I tried to keep the answer very simple and basic

Comment: He also stated that he wants explanations, which you didn't give at all. And since he isn't a programmer I doubt it will be easy to implement for him.

Comment: I've changed the code a little so it works in fiddle, might be useful as a reference in conjunction with Winchestro's answer http://jsfiddle.net/ja8aS/3/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery the following will work

```
function addSingleSelect(classToSelect) {                   // Pass in the name of the class
    $('.' + classToSelect).click(
        function(event) {
            var selected = event.target;                    // Get Selected Click Target 
            $('.' + classToSelect).css('display', 'none');  // Hide EVERYTHING
            $(selected).css('display','')                   // Show the selected item
        }
    ); 
}
```

Assume you had

```
<div id="1" class="MaxPackage">Max 1</div>
<div id="2" class="MaxPackage">Max 2</div>
<div id="3" class="MaxPackage">Max 3</div>
```

you could call

```
addSingleSelect('MaxPackage');
```

and do the same for anything else as well with a different class

**HTML**

```
<div id="4" class="MinPackage">Min 4</div>
<div id="5" class="MinPackage">Min 5</div>
<div id="6" class="MinPackage">Min 6</div>
```

**JS**

```
addSingleSelect('MinPackage');
```